# XPath for child element

Tags: selenium, xpath

What is the **Xpath** to select the first element of this jquery selector: `$('.A  .B:eq(1)') ?`

HTML Sample

```
<div class="x A z">
  <div class="y">
    <div class="r B z"></div>  <---- that is that I need to select
        <div class="r B z"></div

>
...
```

So far I've tried this:

```
(//div[(@class='A') and div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'B')]])[1]
```

Comment: Try with this cssSelector ==> By.cssSelector("div[class*='A'] div[class*='B']:first-child")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' A ')]//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' B ')][1]
```

Comment: I broke up all the competitors that you have chosen my answer :)